# group by date and then by currecny and sum mongo records

Tags: mongodb

I have the following records on my mongo database

```
> db.orders.find({});
{
    "_id" : "WEB3",
    "currency" : "USD",
    "company" : "b",
    "user_id" : "b",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-26T12:13:18.570Z"),
    "details" : {
        "ordered" : {
            "total" : 1910.4,
            "deliveryVAT" : 120,
            "delivery" : 600,
            "goodsVAT" : 198.4,
            "goodsTotal" : 992
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "WEB1",
    "currency" : "GBP",
    "company" : "a",
    "user_id" : "a",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-26T12:11:08.570Z"),
    "details" : {
        "ordered" : {
            "total" : 1910.4,
            "deliveryVAT" : 120,
            "delivery" : 600,
            "goodsVAT" : 198.4,
            "goodsTotal" : 992
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "WEB2",
    "currency" : "GBP",
    "company" : "a",
    "user_id" : "a",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-26T12:11:18.570Z"),
    "details" : {
        "ordered" : {
            "total" : 1910.4,
            "deliveryVAT" : 120,
            "delivery" : 600,
            "goodsVAT" : 198.4,
            "goodsTotal" : 992
        }
    }
}
```

here is the insert, statement:

```
db.orders.insert( { "_id" : "WEB1", "currency" : "GBP", "company" : "a", "user_id" : "a", "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-26T12:11:08.570Z"), "details" : { "ordered" : { "total" : 1910.4, "deliveryVAT" : 120, "delivery" : 600, "goodsVAT" : 198.4, "goodsTotal" : 992 } } });
db.orders.insert( { "_id" : "WEB2", "currency" : "GBP", "company" : "a", "user_id" : "a", "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-26T12:11:18.570Z"), "details" : { "ordered" : { "total" : 1910.4, "deliveryVAT" : 120, "delivery" : 600, "goodsVAT" : 198.4, "goodsTotal" : 992 } } });
db.orders.insert( { "_id" : "WEB3", "currency" : "USD", "company" : "b", "user_id" : "b", "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-26T12:13:18.570Z"), "details" : { "ordered" : { "total" : 1910.4, "deliveryVAT" : 120, "delivery" : 600, "goodsVAT" : 198.4, "goodsTotal" : 992 } } });
```

What is the correct way to group by date and then group by currency, so that I get a result similar to:

```
{ [ "date": "2015-06-26",
  "currency": "USD",
  "total": 1910.4,
  "no_of_orders": 1],
  [ "date": "2015-06-26",
  "currency": "GBP",
  "total": 3820.8,
  "no_of_orders": 2]]
}
```

From a previous post [mongodb sort result of aggregate query and display day name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103624/mongodb-sort-result-of-aggregate-query-and-display-day-name) I am able to get the number of orders made for each day, but then I am unsure how to pipe the results and split those by currency and then total the result?

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following aggregation pipeline which groups the documents by Year-Month-Day and the currency to get the desired results:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": {
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth" : "$timestamp" },
                "month": { "$month" : "$timestamp" },
                "year": { "$year" : "$timestamp" },
                "currency": "$currency"
            }, 
            "total": { "$sum": "$details.ordered.total" },
            "no_of_orders": { "$sum": 1 }
        } 
    },
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "_id": 0, 
            "dateDay": {
                "$concat": [ 
                    {"$substr" : [ "$_id.day", 0, 2]}, "-",
                    {"$substr" : [ "$_id.month", 0, 2]}, "-",
                    {"$substr" : [ "$_id.year", 0, 4]}
                ] 
            },            
            "total": 1,
            "no_of_orders": 1,
            "currency": "$_id.currency"
        }

    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "total" : 1910.4,
            "no_of_orders" : 1,
            "dateDay" : "26-6-2015",
            "currency" : "USD"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 3820.8,
            "no_of_orders" : 2,
            "dateDay" : "26-6-2015",
            "currency" : "GBP"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```